# Pyspark: What type of join can I use?

Tags: python, sql, join, pyspark

To start, I have the following dataframes, A and B. Below is the result I am trying to output the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSlQs.png).

To sum up the goal, I am looking to create a resulting dataframe where:

1. I use df A as the base (it has more columns than B that I'd like to keep)
2. If a value is None in A and a number in B, I take B.
3. If a value is a number in both, I take B.
4. If a value is a number in A but None in B, I take A.

Any suggestions? Also, if there is a way of doing this through a SQL query, that would work as well.

Comment: Something like this? Do a left join first where you alias the col from A and B you want to do operations on. Then use joined_df.withColumn('X' , when((col('A').isNull() & col('B').isNotNull()), col('B')).when((col('A').isNotNull() & col('B').isNull()), col('A')).otherwise(col('B'))

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion. Possible better way of doing this, but this should work. You would need to do this for all columns you want to do this on.

```
a_df = spark.table('table_a').select(PK, x2, col('Original').alias('A')) #dataframe a
b_df = spark.table('table_b').select(PK, col('Original').alias('B')) #dataframe b

joined_df = a_df.join(b_df, a_df.PK == b_df.PK, 'left') #join a on b

result_df = joined_df.withColumn('Original' , 
when((col('A').isNull() & col('B').isNotNull()), col('B'))\
.when((col('A').isNotNull() & col('B').isNull()), col('A')).otherwise(col('B')))

#If A is Null & B is not Null, then B
#If A is not Null & B is Null, then A
#Otherwise (if both are Null, both are not null) then B
```

Comment: You can use `coalesce` instead of chain of `when`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did come across the when function and coalesce, but because I have a variable number of columns to run this on, I put it in a loop. With that, I was getting a StackOverflow error. Is there a way to avoid this? Perhaps a SQL solution?